# DOMPDF - How to write text on top of another PDF file (PHP)

Tags: pdf, merge, pdf-generation, overlay, dompdf

Say for example I wanted to load an already existing PDF file, and then transpose text on top of that PDF file and save it again as a new PDF file. Essentially merging the two, with one being transposed on the other.

I don't want the PDF acting as the background to become an image as to lose quality, so that everything retains it's original vectored format.

How would I go about doing this merge?

I don't want to use software, maybe there's a script that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dompdf itself is unable to perform this kind of action. You would need to generate your PDF documents independently then use a third-party library to merge the two documents.

Since you're using dompdf I'm guessing you might be looking for a PHP-based solution. Take a look at [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/). After generating your PDF documents with dompdf you could then use FPDI to combine them.

I think this will work, *but I haven't tested it*:

```
<?php
// generate pdf documents
require_once('dompdf/autoload.inc.php');

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('<p>Hello</p>');
$dompdf->render();
file_put_contents('doc1.pdf', $dompdf->output());

unset($dompdf);

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('<p>&nbsp;</p><p>Hello</p>');
$dompdf->render();
file_put_contents('doc2.pdf', $dompdf->output());


// combine pdf documents
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI('L');
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file to doc1.pdf and import a page
$pdf->setSourceFile("doc1.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 210 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 210);
// set the source file to doc2.pdf and import a page
$pdf->setSourceFile("doc2.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 100,10 with a width of 210 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 100, 10, 210);

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: I tested it this works , also a great solution for overlapping pdf over one another .

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear within what context you're planning to do this, and your process description suggests that you want to *superimpose* (or overset) text on top of the existing content, not transpose it. If you are opening the document with any utility that supports parsing the input PDF and accepting new content as new PDF objects, there is nothing to prevent you from dropping new text on top of older text. If viewing onscreen, the old material will be rendered first, followed by any newer material occupying the same (x,y) coordinates. In other words, the existing PDF material does not need to be rendered to image form before new content can be applied over it.

Note, however, that if you're planning to redact existing material by writing over it, this will not be the way to do it, as the newer/upper objects do not directly affect others underneath. It can be possible to drag the upper objects aside (using Acrobat, for example) to see whatever's under them.

Comment: I'm sorry about the lack of clarity, through some time spent in answering my own question, I've boiled it down to how I would go about doing this: taking an existing PDF file, and writing an HTML produced PDF file on top, merging the two.